# One liner code for three level up in folder path

Tags: python-3.x, path

Is there a one liner code to reach three level up of a path using python?

Currently my code is a three liner as I am using os.path.split and going step by step. However, the paths intermediate steps are unnecessary for my purpose, hence I would like to jump directly to the path three levels up. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path
three_levels_up = Path('your path').parents[2]
```

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a wonderful replacement to `os.path`.